# Difference between ways to specify target path in Spark Structured Streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, delta-lake, apache-iceberg

In [Spark Structured Streaming](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html) the target path of streaming write operations can be specified either by adding an `.option('path', <target path>)` or as argument to the `.start(<target path>)` method. The latter seems to be preferred with [Delta Lake](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-streaming.html#delta-table-as-a-sink), the former with [Iceberg](https://iceberg.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-structured-streaming/). Is there any difference between the two or can they be used interchangeably?